# how to assign cacheItemUpdateCallBack to cache

Tags: caching, user-controls, delegates, shopping-cart

I am developing an eCommerce website in which user will buy the product.
for the i have made a cache and add the item to cache. i have made the usercontrol of product with the add button(for buy the product  which add the item to cart).
add button will call the fallowing method

```
public void itemAddTocart(string[] arg, int itemQty)
        {
            CartDT=(DataTable)Cache["Cart"];
            if (CartDT==null)
            {
                DataTableColumn();
            }
            DataRow dr = CartDT.NewRow();
            dr[0] = arg[0];  //Product_Name
            dr[1] = arg[1]; //Product_ID
            dr[2] = itemQty; //OrderQTY
            dr[3] = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(arg[2])).ToString(); //Price
            dr[4] = (Double.Parse(arg[2]) * itemQty).ToString(); // calculate total price
            dr[5] = 0;
            dr[6] = "default";
            dr[7] = Convert.ToInt32(arg[3]);
            dr[8] = arg[4];
            dr[9] = arg[5];
            dr[10] = arg[6];

                dr[11] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["MinorderAmount"].ToString());

            CartDT.Rows.Add(dr);
            //CartDT.DefaultView.Sort = "SuppEmailID";
            Cache["cart"] = CartDT;


        }
```

but after adding item to cart have to show the changes in cart to user for that i am refresh the whole  page so the the code in page load will populate the cart which will be take long time which will not good for user  am doing so because this event is trigger from user control so that i do not have the access the page control

so that i have decide to call the method which will be trigger when cache is update by using **CacheItemUpdateCallback delegate**

which will be added as

Create Deligate

```
CacheItemUpdateCallback CacheItemUpdateCallbackDel=new CacheItemUpdateCallback (CacheItemUpdateCallbackMethod);
```

Add it

```
 Cache.Insert("ProductData", PD, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemUpdateCallbackDel);
```

Method

```
public void CacheItemUpdateCallbackMethod(string key, CacheItemUpdateReason reason, out object expensiveObject, out CacheDependency dependency, out DateTime absoluteExpiration, out TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
        {
             setCartSuppWise();
        }
```

but it gives me the error

**The out parameter 'expensiveObject' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method**

**The out parameter 'dependency' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method**

**The out parameter 'absoluteExpiration' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method**

**The out parameter 'slidingExpiration' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method**

am first time working with the cache so i may have been make the mistake or may be making  wrong concept so please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Looks like this parameters need some value to be assigned in the  CacheItemUpdateCallbackMethod method

Answer (score 0):

The CacheItemUpdateCallback specifies "out" parameters. Out parameters must always be set before the function returns. "You should provide the new cached item and optional expiration and dependency values to use when refreshing the cached item.".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemupdatecallback(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public void CacheItemUpdateCallbackMethod(string key, CacheItemUpdateReason reason, out       object expensiveObject, out CacheDependency dependency, out DateTime absoluteExpiration, out TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
{
    expensiveObject = your_object;
    dependency = ...
    absoluteExpiration = ...
    slidingExpiration = ...
}
```